# How can I solve 'Error: Unable to start debugging' issue for outlook add in react project?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, outlook, outlook-web-addins

I created outlook add-in project by following steps mention in below training module.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/office-add-ins-outlook/3-exercise-mail-basics
but after executing 'npm start or npm run start' getting below error without any details.

[error snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdBrc.png)

Debugging is being started...
App type: desktop
Error: Unable to start debugging.

I have installed required prequisites mentioned in module.
which are :

- Node.js - (the active LTS version)
- npm (installed with Node.js)
- Yeoman - v4.x (or higher)
- Yeoman Generator for Microsoft Office - v1.9.5
- Visual Studio Code (VS Code) or your preferred code editor

current installation versions

node v20.10.0
npm  10.2.5

How can I resolve this? What am I missing?

I tried reinstalling node, visual studio code and also tried clearing data from appdata and temp folder. But still getting same problem.